# Error: Couldn't open PDF file 'MJVQKFFGFEPBI.TMP' for writing (permission denied)

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions, pdflib

I'm using `pdflib` to dynamically create the `pdf` docs in `PHP`, but for some reason the error message I receive is this

```
Error: Couldn't open PDF file 'MJVQKFFGFEPBI.TMP' for writing (permission denied)
```

The error which triggers the line is this

```
if (!pdf_begin_document($this->p, $this->output_file, ($linearize ? 'linearize' : ''))) die('Error: ' . pdf_get_errmsg($this->p));
```

My question is how it would be possible to get the location of the directory for which the permission is denied or is this error triggered by any other reason?

The same code works in my server `ubuntu 12.04` but not in `12.10`

Answer (score 1):

I just got the information from Rainer Plöckl from PDFlib that you need to either specify the `inmemory` and/or the `tempdirname`-option for `begin_document` when you use either `linearize` or `optimize`. By default pdflib tries to open a temporary file **in the current directory** where he webserver-user might not have the right to create new files.

I had the same issue with `optimize` and circumvented that issue by using this code:

```
pdf_begin_document($this->p, '', 'optimize=true tempdirname=' . sys_get_temp_dir());
```

After that everything worked fine.

you can find the relevant part of the documentation at http://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/manuals/PDFlib-9.0.4-API-reference.pdf#page=48

Answer (score 0):

[`sys_get_temp_dir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php) tells you the name of the directory for temporary files. You can use this to create a temporary file:

```
$filename = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir());
```

Then pass `$filename` to `pdf_begin_document` as a second parameter.

Comment: Use that directory to create a temporary file as described in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Although I was using windows and there was no such issue with permissions.
So that's how I have fixed my issue.

Below is an example of the issue I was facing while reading the logs in PDFlib project. I was not using absolute paths.

```
    $p->set_option("errorpolicy=exception");
    $p->set_option("SearchPath={{" . $searchpath . "}}");
    $p->set_option("logging={filename=logs/debug.log remove}");
```

Then I have added the path to the logs directory and that fixed the issue.

```
$defaultPath =  dirname(__FILE__);
$p->set_option("logging={filename={$defaultPath}/logs/debug.log remove}");
```